# ctor is not a constructor. Angular7 unit testing

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular7

I am writing a unit test case for a component which uses a service.
While testing i am getting following error:

`ctor is not a constructor`

How to resolve this error?

[image: ctor is not a constructor - error screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In beforeEach function replace `useClass` with `useValue`, inside providers.

```js
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    service = jasmine.createSpyObj('ContactService', ['getContacts']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [CityComponent],
      providers: [{provide: ContactService, useValue: service}]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```